# Sudden In-App Purchase Problems with Windows Phone 8.0 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, in-app-purchase

For about a year now, we have a **Windows Phone (8.0**, not yet 8.1 or 10) app, in which we offer IAPs. Unfortunately, since a recent update, the IAPs are not shown anymore when we fetch a list of all registered IAPs for our app. So, the **app can't load the product-listing information anymore** from the Windows Phone Store (in the public and beta version).

From our version control system we realized that an app Id in the manifest file changed with the last update. In the last update, we migrated the project to Xamarin (as we also have this app for Android and iOS), but this should have no influence on the native WindowsPhone client as it doesn't need Xamarin. That's why we re-submitted the beta with the old app id and also submitted an old xap where we were sure that it had worked. **Both re-submissions were without success**.

When we test the product-listing information from the store we get the following response (through Fiddler Web Debugger):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <BatchGetIapDetailsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.zune.net/catalog/apps/2008/02">
    <Resources />
 </BatchGetIapDetailsResponse>
```

We also read something abaout a new identity-name which is important for apps, but this shouldn't have an influence on our WP 8.0 app (as it's used for WP8.1). We also can't remember having changed anything with the IAPs in the Store.

Did someone have similar issues or ideas what else we could try to fix the issue? Any **suggestions** are appreciated a lot.